# Making sure the Admin account is undeletable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a second year undergrad designing a ruby on rail program for
wedding.

I am struggling so much with lots of code but one main thing which I
don't understand how to do is to make sure that the administrator doesn't delete their
own account in the process, as is currently the case.

Please can someone help me? I know it is a code within user
controller.rb which has "def destroy" but I don't know how to go about
doing that.

This is the code I have so far:

```
  def destroy
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if not user.role = 'admin'
@user.destroy
else 
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to users_path, 
notice: "#{@user.name} is an admin. You do not have permission to delete this user" }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
```

end

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest extracting all that logic into an instance method. This way it would be much easier to use and implement new rules in the future in you need to.

In your `user.rb` file:

```
def safe_destroy
  return false if admin?
  destroy
end

def admin?
  role == 'admin'
end
```

In your controller:

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.safe_destroy
    # do something
  else
    # do something else
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 for using instance method logic in controller, nice and clean!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line

```
if not user.role = 'admin'
```

Should be `==`

```
unless user.role == 'admin'
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things

First you need to have a redirection when the user is not admin.
I would also use the syntax if user.role != 'admin'

```
if user.role != 'admin'
  @user.destroy
  redirect_to users_path
else
```

Michael

Comment: An often seen method however it violates the skinny controller fat models principle..